# custom sort order on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I know we can define our custom sort function of array of json objects. But what if the order is neither `desc nor asc`. For example lets say my array looks like:

```
[ {
    name: 'u'
  },
  {
    name: 'n'
  },
  {
    name: 'a'
  },
  { 
    name: 'n',
  } 
]
```

Output should look like:

```
[ {
    name: 'n'
  },
  {
    name: 'n'
  },
  {
    name: 'a'
  },
  { 
    name: 'u',
  } 
]
```

Where all the names starting with `n` are sorted first and then the rest. I have tried the following custom sort function:

```
_sortByName(a, b){
        if (a.name === 'n'){
            return 1;
        } else if(b.name === 'n'){
            return 1;
        } else if(a.name < b.name){
            return 1;
        } else if(a.name > b.name){
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

But the order returned for objects is wrong. What is going wrong here?

Comment: What is it returning now?

Comment: `if (a.name === 'n')` and `if (b.name === 'n')` both return `1`, which appears to be incorrect.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you have an arbitrary sort order, one option is to assign the order to an array and then use `indexOf`:

```js
var sortOrder = ['n', 'a', 'u'];
var myArray = [{
    name: 'u'
  },
  {
    name: 'n'
  },
  {
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    name: 'n'
  }
];
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return sortOrder.indexOf(a.name) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.name);
});

console.log(myArray);
```

If you have many values in either array, it might be worthwhile creating a value-index map first and then using `sortOrder[a.name]`.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) here

```js
const dict = "nau";
var myArray = [
  {
    name: "u",
  },
  {
    name: "n",
  },
  {
    name: "a",
  },
  {
    name: "n",
  },
];

myArray.sort((a, b) => dict.indexOf(a.name) - dict.indexOf(b.name));

console.log(myArray);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**2)** You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here

I've added some gap/space in between two `character` because there can be other character that will come between them, so you can place in between them

```js
const order = {
  n: 100,
  a: 200,
  u: 300,
};

var myArray = [
  {
    name: "u",
  },
  {
    name: "n",
  },
  {
    name: "a",
  },
  {
    name: "n",
  },
];
myArray.sort((a, b) => order[a.name] - order[b.name]);

console.log(myArray);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```