# Javascript custom sort

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've implement this sort:

```
<tbody>
  {results.sort((a, b) => a.status > b.status ? 1 : -1).map(el => {
    return (
    <tr>
      <td>{el.id}</td>
      <td>{el.amount}</td>
      <td>{el.time}</td>
      <td>{el.status}</td>
     
    </tr> 
    );
  })}
  </tbody>
```

So now I have them sorted by status as follows: active, updated, waiting. The problem is that I want them sorted by active, waiting, updated. How can I achieve this?

This is my array of objects:

```
 const data = [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "Order 1",
          amount: 3,
          status: "active"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Order 2",
          amount: 5,
          status: "waiting"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Order 3",
          amount: 4,
          status: "updated"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "Order 4",
          amount: 3,
          status: "active"
        }
      ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom sort order on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211544/custom-sort-order-on-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to an ordered array, with this approach:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Order 1",
    amount: 3,
    status: "active"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Order 2",
    amount: 5,
    status: "waiting"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Order 3",
    amount: 4,
    status: "updated"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Order 4",
    amount: 3,
    status: "active"
  }
];

const statusOrdered = ['active', 'waiting', 'updated']

data.sort((a, b) => statusOrdered.indexOf(a.status) - statusOrdered.indexOf(b.status));

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for your sorting function.

```
(a,b) => {
    let ranking = {
        active:1,
        waiting:2,
        updated:3,
    }
    return ranking[a.status] - ranking[b.status]
}
```